# User Interface Diagram That is always reachable

Tags: user-interface, uml, use-case, uid, visual-paradigm

If you have to build a flow of a Use-case by drawing each Interface Diagram.
Then you would start with a Diagram like say "login".

But after the login page, no mather wich page you choose except the "logout" page,

you always have your navigation bar right ? So all the options in the navigation bar?

Like account page , personal page, etc...

Do you have to make sure in your flow that in every diagram there is acces to the "accountpage" diagram ?

Or do they have an other solution for that ?

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

The Use Case Diagram is used for describing specific events in a system, which are performed by internal and external actors. Internal actors are those users that will directly interact with your system, such as an admin, a customer, or even time can be an internal actor. External actors are those other users or other systems that communicate with your system.

Therefore, this type of diagram is not useful for depicting what you want to represent. Since you are using UML to define your system. There are different diagrams you could implement, such as the following:

- Such as a collaboration diagram which captures the behavior and structure of the user interface model. This type of diagram represents a visual flow, that involves the related actors and events for a given use case specification or a set of them. Another characteristic of the collaboration diagram is that besides showing the behavior it also details relationships.
- For depicting the interaction at class level, you could use a modified version of the class diagram, where for each class you would only show its name and the public methods, having in mind readability. Then inserting the corresponding actors that interact with each of those classes.
- Another diagram, would be the sequence diagram, which provides a step by step description of the interactions which can include actors and events.

On the other hand, outside of the UML realm, if you just want to show a basic layout and graphical interaction with the different components in your page, I would recommend usign wireframes.

Comment: Hi. I don't want to make an use case diagram. I want to make an user interface diagrams. But does every interface diagram needs a link to the accountpage ?

Comment: Yes, but if you have common elements that would have to show up in different diagrams, perhaps you could group those elements into one diagram. Then reference that grouping in every interface diagram that needs it.

Comment: Thanx for the answer! So in other words I need to group the account page interface diagrams, and then put a link to every other diagram! That solved my problem! thanx